# Show mac-address table on custom interface in FreeBSD and Linux

Tags: freebsd, mac-address

On switches I can show mac addresses on any port by "show mac-address-table port X"
Is there any way to do this on FreeBSD and Linux systems?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Sorry, but [SF] is for Professional System Administrators (et al) only. Your question appears to be for non-professional use and might be on-topic on [SU] or [unix.SE], but you should search their sites and check their FAQs before posting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tcpdump -e -i eth0` works find for me

Answer (score 1):

Try the `arp -a` command, at least this works on FreeBSD.

Comment: what about pppoe server. There is no IPs, so ARP table will be empty.